# VS Code integrated terminal cannot find pip3 installed packages for python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, pip

I installed Python 3.9.4 and pip3 from homebrew, and then I made 3.9.4 as default on my mac by following this [guide](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac).
When I open my terminal and run

```
pip3 --version
```

I get this

```
pip 21.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

but when I open VS code's integrated terminal and run the same command, I get this

```
pip 21.1.1 from /Users/vibhorsagar/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

I don't understand why its showing me two different locations of pip3 installed.
Due to this, any package I install from terminal, they aren't recognized by VS code for some reason and any script I run it gives me

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

Comment: a) Make sure you chose the right interpreter ind VS Code (a virtual environment seems to be active) b) run the pip command in the internal terminal.

Comment: How do I check if a virtual environment is active?